# How to use ADO.NET asynchronous methods in .NET Core without Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I believe Entity Framework Core is slow for the application that I am working on. It is a .NET Core Web API. I need to convert it to use ADO.NET and at the same time take advantage of asynchronous programming that is easy in Entity Framework Core. Any resources or direction will help me kick start my migration.

Comment: You could look into learning about dapper.

Comment: Why do you believe EF Core is slow?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but something like this would allow you to use ADO.NET objects:

```
var con = ctx.Database.GetDbConnection();
var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "...";
var rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
```